# PowerShell not able to return last 10 created folders based on creation time

Tags: powershell

How can I get the list of the newest 10 items (here folders) created in the `$startDirectory` no matter when we run the code (show last 10 created)?

I tried adding another filer into `Where-Object` like `-and $_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)` but this is not returning anything

I also tried  adding `-Descending -Property LastWriteTime -Top 10` to `Sort-Object` still didn't work!

```
$startDirectory = '\\dd_exchange\content\maps'
$directoryItems = Get-ChildItem $startDirectory | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true} | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime -Top 10
foreach ($i in $directoryItems)
{
    $subFolderItems = Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -recurse -force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | Measure-Object -property Length -sum | Select-Object Sum
    $i.FullName + " -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum ) + " GB"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove the where-object filtering for folder by adding -Directory to GCI.  I get an error when adding -TOP 10.  However the below worked as expected for me.

```
$startDirectory = 'Y:\My Drive\Source\GIT'
$directoryItems = Get-ChildItem $startDirectory -Directory | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | select-object -First 10
foreach ($i in $directoryItems)
{
    $subFolderItems = Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -recurse -force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | Measure-Object -property Length -sum | Select-Object Sum
    $i.FullName + " -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum ) + " GB"
}
```